# Why am I not able to see my answer from a question which was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Just a few minutes ago I noticed that a question where I wrote an answer was deleted. So I tried to see my answer again.

[image]

But I can only see three (deleted by my own) of my four deleted answers. (I can't see the last one..19h..deleted because question was deleted.)

Why is that not possible? Because the question was deleted and not only my answer? Is it possible that I can see why the question was deleted where I wrote an answer for? (I know that the question was not good, but it just had one downvote.)

Was it deleted from the user itself, or from a moderator because it was too bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question itself is deleted, the all the answers to that question are implicitly deleted, too. And since you cannot see deleted questions (until you have 10k+ reputation), you can't see your answer anymore, either.

In this case, [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697224/resizing-svg-icons) was deleted by its original author, Ned. The system allowed him to do that because there were no *upvoted* answers on his question. (If your answer would have received an upvote, it would have blocked Ned from deleting the question and taking your work with it.)

For reference, here is the text of your answer:

---

You can change the size of an svg with the viewbox.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 55" width="100" height="50">
      <use xlink:href="#potofgold"/>
    </svg>
```

If you increase the width and height of the viewbox the svg gets resized.

If you change the viewbox the position is changing.
See this example:

```css
svg{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <symbol id="potofgold" >

        <path fill="url(#pot)" stroke="#751" stroke-width="0.5"
              d="M10.156 3.875q1.895 0 3.525.859t2.646 2.471 1.016 3.584q0 1.836-1.006 3.418t-2.666 2.49-3.516.908H6.913q-1.855 0-3.457-.908t-2.529-2.49-.928-3.418q0-1.992.938-3.584t2.51-2.461 3.467-.869h3.242zM6.934 17.02q1.719 0 3.164-.84t2.285-2.285.84-3.164q0-1.699-.84-3.145t-2.285-2.285-3.164-.84q-1.699 0-3.145.84T1.504 7.586t-.84 3.145q0 1.719.84 3.164t2.285 2.285 3.145.84zm-1.426-2.579q-1.133-.43-1.836-1.445t-.723-2.266q.02-1.25.732-2.275t1.826-1.436v7.422zM8.379 7.02q1.113.41 1.826 1.436t.713 2.275-.713 2.266-1.826 1.445V7.02z"
          />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<figure>
  <figcaption>50x25</figcaption>
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 60 55" width="50" height="25">
      <use xlink:href="#potofgold"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>100x50</figcaption>
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 55" width="100" height="50">
      <use xlink:href="#potofgold"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>200x100</figcaption>
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 55" width="200" height="100">
      <use xlink:href="#potofgold"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</figure>
```

EDIT:

I can't look in your code.
But if I change it directly in the browser it works fine:

[image]

In the orange box I add the width attribute to your first sgv. (only the first is affected)

Add / change this class in your css:

```
.icon-discover{
    width:60px;
}
```

In the green box I just changed the existing width which affets all svgs.

Add/change this class in your css:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like another case of "I got my answer, so I wipe my traces" type of OP.

Comment: Maybe, @Tom. But the question also received a couple of downvotes and close votes, which may have scared off a new user.

Comment: Yes, that might be true as well. (I can't see the question and its amount of DVs)

Comment: @Tom: 2 downvotes, no upvotes. 3 votes to close at time of deletion. 3 close votes all of type "Off Topic - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."